# Windows expand over 2 monitors in quad-monitor setup

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors, twinview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graphics cards so I can have 4 monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78869/graphics-cards-so-i-can-have-4-monitors)

i just installed ubuntu 11.10 with my previous hardware setup: 4 monitors and 2 identical nvidia graphic cards.

draging windows around all 4 monitors works nice, but when i maximize a window it expand always over 2 screens. (2x twinview).

i had an workaround for this in 11.04 but cant remember what it was... 
may one of you guys have quad monitors up and running with window maximizing on only one screen

my xorg.conf looks like this:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 280.13  (buildd@allspice)  Thu Aug 11 20:54:45 UTC 2011

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 280.13  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03.nvidia.com)  Wed Jul 27 17:15:58 PDT 2011

Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 0 1080
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2220N"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2220N"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "TwinView" "True"
# Removed Option "MetaModes" "nvidia-auto-select, nvidia-auto-select"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT-0: nvidia-auto-select 1920x1080 +0+0, CRT-1: nvidia-auto-select 1920x1080 +1920+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, CRT-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "TwinView" "True"
# Removed Option "MetaModes" "nvidia-auto-select, nvidia-auto-select"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT-0: nvidia-auto-select 1920x1080 +0+0, CRT-1: nvidia-auto-select 1920x1080 +1920+0"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, CRT-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Comment: It's fairly unusual to have four monitors, so please file a bug with the issues you have. Issues don't get fixed until someone know that there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is not to use twinview.
Using twinview the window system recognizes your screen as the sum of the two monitors and acts accordingly. Full screen applications also would span two screens this way.

Run `sudo nvidia-settings` and disable twin view.